# Setting up a proxy for a specific program, like Bluestacks.

Tags: terminal, cmd, bluestacks, proxies

I am using ubot to manipulate droid apps via bluestacks. I've been stuck for over a day now trying to figure out the best way to setup a proxy, just for bluestacks. I've read about ProxyCap and Proxifier, but is there any way to do this via command line?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think proxycap will work dude... i did all 

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83730/unable-to-use-bluestack-with-proxycap

Answer (score -2):

You can use a program called ProxyCap to set the proxy for bluestacks. ProxyCap 5.27 is the latest version. It works really well, with only 1 catch. It's not freeware. So there is a 31 day free trial period, until you can find something else. I'm busy searching for an alternative now too...

But for the next 31 days, you're sorted.

Comment: In the question user mentioned that ProxyCap is not an option